# Composables in Row are not displayed side by side

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm following https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-sports-app?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-4-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-practice-sports-app#1

Code here: https://github.com/google-developer-training/basic-android-kotlin-compose-training-sports/tree/starter

My changes:

```
diff --git a/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt b/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt
index 7a24a19..48d0941 100644
--- a/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt
+++ b/AndroidBasicsCourse/Sports/app/src/main/java/com/example/sports/ui/SportsScreens.kt
@@ -48,6 +48,7 @@ import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
 import androidx.compose.material3.Text
 import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBar
 import androidx.compose.material3.TopAppBarDefaults
+import androidx.compose.material3.windowsizeclass.WindowWidthSizeClass
 import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
 import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
 import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
@@ -76,6 +77,8 @@ import com.example.sports.ui.theme.SportsTheme
  */
 @Composable
 fun SportsApp(
+    windowSize: WindowWidthSizeClass,
+    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
 ) {
     val viewModel: SportsViewModel = viewModel()
     val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
@@ -260,7 +263,7 @@ private fun SportsList(
 private fun SportsDetail(
     selectedSport: Sport,
     onBackPressed: () -> Unit,
-    contentPadding: PaddingValues,
+    contentPadding: PaddingValues = PaddingValues(0.dp),
     modifier: Modifier = Modifier
 ) {
     BackHandler {
@@ -342,6 +345,35 @@ private fun SportsDetail(
     }
 }
 
+@Composable
+fun SportsListAndDetails(
+    uiState: SportsUiState,
+    viewModel: SportsViewModel,
+    onFinish: () -> Unit = {},
+    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
+) {
+    Row(modifier = modifier) {
+        SportsList(
+            sports = uiState.sportsList,
+            onClick = {
+                viewModel.updateCurrentSport(it)
+                viewModel.navigateToDetailPage()
+            },
+            modifier = Modifier
+                .fillMaxWidth()
+                .padding(
+                    top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                    start = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                    end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                )
+        )
+        SportsDetail(
+            selectedSport = uiState.currentSport,
+            onBackPressed = onFinish
+        )
+    }
+}
+
 @Preview
 @Composable
 fun SportsListItemPreview() {
@@ -365,3 +397,15 @@ fun SportsListPreview() {
         }
     }
 }
+
+@Preview
+@Composable
+fun SportsListAndDetailsPreview() {
+    SportsTheme {
+        Surface {
+            val viewModel: SportsViewModel = viewModel()
+            val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
+            SportsListAndDetails(uiState = uiState, viewModel = viewModel)
+        }
+    }
+}
```

instead of seeing a preview of the form:

[image]

I see just the list of items:

[image]

I tried adding `modifier.weight(1f)` however I think the issue stems from `SportsList` composable not having `modifier.weight(1f)` applied to `LazyColumn` (I tried adding it, however I get an error with both Column and ColumnInstanceScope when importing modifier.weight).

I would have expected the Row to display the list and the detail side by side as in the first image above.

Any hints on how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I looked at the solution for `SportsListAndDetails` and applied the `Modifier.weight(...)` again and it worked this time. Unsure why.

```
+@Composable
+fun SportsListAndDetails(
+    uiState: SportsUiState,
+    viewModel: SportsViewModel,
+    onClick: (Sport) -> Unit,
+    onFinish: () -> Unit = {},
+    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
+) {
+    Row(modifier = modifier) {
+        SportsList(
+            sports = uiState.sportsList,
+            onClick = onClick,
+            modifier = Modifier
+                .weight(2f)
+                .fillMaxWidth()
+                .padding(
+                    top = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                    start = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                    end = dimensionResource(R.dimen.padding_medium),
+                )
+        )
+        SportsDetail(
+            selectedSport = uiState.currentSport,
+            onBackPressed = onFinish,
+            modifier = Modifier.weight(2f)
+        )
+    }
+}
```

They display now, though as if they would be displayed in Compact mode.

Comment: how are you even coding... which ide are you using??? why are there so many characters in your code that are not part of the code...

Comment: @HaseebHassanAsif looks like a git diff or similar

Comment: Preview can be fixed by including `device = Devices.TABLET` as parameter: `@Preview(device = Devices.TABLET)`